# The problem of pagination orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

I have been dealing with this problem for almost 1 month, I read many sources, But I did not reach a basic conclusion. I changed my-account to account, I want to pagination the orders like this : /account/orders/page/2 and ...

I use the following code on the orders page :

path : /plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php

```
    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'base'          => str_replace( 99999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 99999999999 ) ) ),
                    'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
                    'total'         => $customer_orders->max_num_pages,
                    'current'       => $current_page,
                    'show_all'      => false,
                    'end_size'      => 3,
                    'mid_size'      => 3,
                    'prev_next'     => true,
                    'prev_text'     => __( 'Previous', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'next_text'     => __( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'          => 'list',
                    'add_args'      => false,
                    'add_fragment'  => '',
                );
                echo paginate_links( $args );
            ?>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And I put the value of $current_page equal to the values ​​below :

`$current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );`

or

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
     $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
     $current_page = get_query_var('page');
} else {
     $current_page = 1;
}
```

But when I go to other pages it still shows the first page results, The query is as follows :

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => Array
        (
            [pagename] => account
            [orders] => page/2
            [view-order] => page/2
            [debug-this] => wp_query
        )

    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [pagename] => account
            [orders] => page/2
            [view-order] => page/2
            [debug-this] => wp_query
            [error] => 
            [m] => 
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => account
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [s] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [title] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [embed] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_name__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post_parent__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [author__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [post_type] => 
            [posts_per_page] => 6
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 3
            [no_found_rows] => 
            [order] => DESC
        )

    [tax_query] => 
    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
            [meta_table] => 
            [meta_id_column] => 
            [primary_table] => 
            [primary_id_column] => 
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [clauses:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [has_or_relation:protected] => 
        )

    [date_query] => 
    [queried_object] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 88
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-10-06 10:44:32
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-06 07:14:32
            [post_content] => <!-- wp:shortcode -->
<p>[woocommerce_my_account]</p>
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
            [post_title] => my account
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => account
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2022-05-14 11:48:15
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2022-05-14 07:18:15
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/site.com/my-account/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => page
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [queried_object_id] => 88
    [request] => 
            SELECT   wp_posts.*
            FROM wp_posts 
            WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '88') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page'
            
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
            
        
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 88
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [post_date] => 2021-10-06 10:44:32
                    [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-06 07:14:32
                    [post_content] => <!-- wp:shortcode -->
<p>[woocommerce_my_account]</p>
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
                    [post_title] => my account
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [comment_status] => closed
                    [ping_status] => closed
                    [post_password] => 
                    [post_name] => account
                    [to_ping] => 
                    [pinged] => 
                    [post_modified] => 2022-05-14 11:48:15
                    [post_modified_gmt] => 2022-05-14 07:18:15
                    [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 0
                    [guid] => http://localhost/site.com/my-account/
                    [menu_order] => 0
                    [post_type] => page
                    [post_mime_type] => 
                    [comment_count] => 0
                    [filter] => raw
                )

        )

    [post_count] => 1
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [post] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 88
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2021-10-06 10:44:32
            [post_date_gmt] => 2021-10-06 07:14:32
            [post_content] => <!-- wp:shortcode -->
<p>[woocommerce_my_account]</p>
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
            [post_title] => my account
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => account
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2022-05-14 11:48:15
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2022-05-14 07:18:15
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/site.com/my-account/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => page
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 1
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 1
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_privacy_policy] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_embed] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 1
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_favicon] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => da6d9c32319765db896a0f249162b59c
    [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
    [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => query_vars_hash
            [1] => query_vars_changed
        )

    [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => init_query_flags
            [1] => parse_tax_query
        )

)
```

I tested one way and came to a conclusion, but I know that this is not a principled way, I set the  $current_page value as below and the pages are coming fine :

```
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/2' ) {
    $current_page = 1;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/2' ) {
    $current_page = 2;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/3' ) {
    $current_page = 3;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/4' ) {
    $current_page = 4;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/5' ) {
    $current_page = 5;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/6' ) {
    $current_page = 6;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/7' ) {
    $current_page = 7;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/8' ) {
    $current_page = 8;
}
if ( $wp->query_vars['orders'] === 'page/9' ) {
    $current_page = 9;
}
```

I had asked the same question yesterday, but this time I explained it in more detail so that maybe my friends can guide me, **I am asking my friends to guide me**. I appreciate any advice from you.

Answer (score 0):

get_pagenum_link is wrong in your case

Woo uses its own endpoints so you need to change your base

```
'base' => str_replace( 99999999999, '%#%', esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url('orders', 99999999999 ) ) ),
```

That will return /orders/2/ , /orders/3/ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the pagination will be as you said, but I want it to be like this, as I asked in my question: /account/orders/page/2 , /account/orders/page/3 etc.

Comment: Since woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query loop orders with get_posts() ill suggest make your own query and then you should not have problems.